# DTAP Environment in SDL Tridion

Tags: cme

I need to know how to Set UP DTAP(Development,Test,Acceptance,Production) environment in SDL Tridion? I need to know understanding for below point in context of DTAP.

1. Do we need to have separate server for each environment? and need to have separate license for each Tridion environment  server?
2. On Development server,do developer needs to create the actual content? or actual content is created on Acceptance server by author? if actual content is created by author on acceptance server then how it will be tested and verified by tester.
3. if one phase of development is completed in DTAP environment,and second phase of development is needs to started,in that case do we needs to all regression testing again which include test cases of phase 1 too. because we are working same phase one developer environment for phase two too.
4. what would be the best approach too deal with DTAP set up environment.

Answer (score 6):

There is no ONE practice or fix steps to setup the DTAP as it entirely depends on the various business requirements, scenarios and even the non-functional requirements (like performance benchmarking etc.). But in most general case below is the high level guidelines:

1. **YES**, it is recommended that you must have a separate server for each environment so that there is no conflict in environment. Although you can have implementations/Configurations which may allow you to have two or more environment on same server, but you may end up having overheads in managing them. Further it may also be recommended to have separate servers for Content Manager, Content Delivery and Tridion Databases to have smooth experience and this may depends entirely on the business requirements and your model of working primarily.
   Further, **YES** you need to have a separate license for each of the environment - Content Manager and Content Delivery both
2. It's up to you and entirely depends on your Model of working. If you can get the Actual content before the development starts and get confirmation from the client that it won't get changed much going forward, you can have actual content entry at Dev environment. This will have benefit of identifying all the bugs related to Content (Example: HTML layout messed up due to large content, Component Linking taking huge publishing time as actual content suggest the components to link are in Hundreds etc.). Else, you are not left with an option but to have the content entry on the Acceptance environment. In my personal experience I have seen implementation where the actual content has been entered on the Production environment as well (due to unavailability of the approved content )
3. I think your QA lead/consultant would be the right person to answer this, Usually in any typical development cycle, Regression Test Cases are created even before development. If these test scenario are there in second phase of development, yes you have to go through the regression again, if they are not, you should not. Personally, if in the second phase there is any functional change or template/code change including css/js, Yes I would go for a regression testing.
4. There is no one best approach as it entirely depends on requirements. Personally, if cost is not in picture, I would go for below as it may allow me more scalability and flexibility:

   - Dev Environment - Separate one server for CM, CD and DB each, All development here with as much possible real content
   - Test Environment - Separate one server each for CM, CD and DB; all testing done here
   - Acceptance & Production - Should be in sync in configuration. I would recommend a cluster of multiple servers for each CM, CD and DB
   - You should also have a plan/process in place for syncing the data back from Production to Acceptance to Test to Dev environment.

Further, as I said it all depends on the actual business requirement - Not only how you setup DTAP but also whether you have to use DTAP or not.

I hope it helps you somewhat and good luck with SDL Tridion.

Answer (score 3):

There's a huge amount of discussion and explanation about sdl tridion and dtap online, have you performed a basic google search?

Whilst DTAP is a common scenario it's also common to see other environment scenarios depending on the publishing requirements of the business.

I'd recommend reading some of the online documentation, talking to your client and then posting specific questions here.

That said, You'll certainly need licences per installation as the licence is usually tied to the machine name.

Comment: Here is a link to the Hardware Prerequisites in the online documentation (login required): http://bit.ly/ITewpb It has a short DTAP topic but also nicely lists the main Performance variables to take into account when sizing or trying to pinpoint a performance bottleneck.